# Remove injected code from all php files in directory on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, replace

I have a site where some code was injected into a very large number of php files and removing them manually is not feasible due to the number of files.

I can search for a variable name from the injected code in all files and it gives me a list of the affected ones, but I can't put the actual code in the search as it contains double quotes, single quotes and all types of characters.

Here is what I used for the search:

grep -Ril "ljdcvhg" 'path-to-site-folder'

Is there any way to search for the entire php function / injected code and remove? Please note I'm very new to linux.

I was going to put the hack code in here, but I'm not sure if that is allowed or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You were right not to include that code here.  What you're planning to do is a bad idea for many reasons.  It may quite easily have side-effects, the attack possibly (probably) had a variant, and it won't allow you to fix the actual problem.

Comment: Just re-deploy the site. You do use a version control system and have a deployment process defined, right?

Comment: The real solution is to restore your latest backup, change your database passwords, look through the logs to find what actually caused the infiltration and get it fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no backup for this site. It was a wordpress site with woocommerce and got hacked during production without anyone noticing. The hack was discovered by accident after it moved live. Remaking it from scratch is not really an option and it would take a month of work at least.

Comment: @Mankind1023 then you're quite out of luck.  Because spreading the hack code is equivalent to spreading malware, we can't really dig deep into the issue to see how bad you're breached. That said, the code is almost 100% guaranteed to be doing *something* with the host system, whether using it to spread malware via your site, or to be a botnet, or any of an infinite number of other things.  The only *safe* solution is to start over - I'll bet you almost anything that your server's been breached, and is now doing something due to malware, far beyond the 'code injection' you've observed.

Comment: @Mankind1023 ... Also consider this a lesson in proper systems handling and disaster recovery - no backups == ***BAD***.  Start over, clean, then start keeping ***clean backups*** so you can recover from things like this in the future.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who's had their PHP-based front end breached, code injected into it, and took a stab at trying to clean up the injected code themselves (*after* restoring the site from a clean tarball of the framework and modifications I made), allow me to give some real-world expertise and answers: ***the only real answer to fixing this is to start over***.  Trying to clean up the code will be EXTREMELY difficult.  It's likely it's embedded everywhere, and you won't find all of it.  It's also quite likely your system is compromised too, not just the PHP but the core system itself could have malicious software running on it, downloaded via the injected and obfuscated code.

The tried-and-true solution, which is also commonly accepted as the only sane option in situations like these, is to **Nuke It From Orbit<sup>*</sup> and start over from clean backups (or Version-controlled code)**.  Not just the site code, but also the server itself.  Code injected into a PHP site could be running anything from simple portscanning to full blown malware installations on the OS itself, to rootkits.  Therefore, start over, by erasing the server it's on, nuke the site code base, and restore from either clean Version Controlled code or the last clean backup you have.

(TL;DR, don't try and remove all the injected code, just start over on a clean server and restore from backups or Version Controlled repository data)

> Note that I've also breached my own site in a private lab, and proven that obfuscated code can be used to download malware to the host server *and* to clients visiting the infected server... this is why you should nuke the environment and start over from clean backups.  Then, subsequently patch up the hole that was used to inject code on the site.

<sup>*  If you don't know what this means, "Nuke it from orbit" is a colloquial term which basically means shut off the site, turn off the server, and erase the entire hard drive and start over from a fresh installation of the server *and* the site codebase.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

What you can try doing is the following:

- Obtain professional PHP editor with code formatting, for example PHPEclipse, PHP Storm or NuSphere, or even Notepad++, on Linux it's Kate and on MacOS it's TextMate
- You can search all files for given strings and remove them
- You can also format the code again (code formatter, including HTML), so that you can see whatever there's something obfuscated
- If you can see highlighted code, it will help you as well, e.g. whatever is not highlighting properly might be something obfuscated
- You need to read all the code properly
- Editor will help you secure the code from further exploiting
- You need to inspect contest of all files, including pictures, if there isn't any PHP or JS code in PNG or JPEG images.
- You might need to upgrade PHP runtime to something with up to date patches, or even migrate it to newer PHP7 and keep it up to date.
- You can use Cloud Flare to defend against exploits
- You might consider different hosting, or recreated account
- Sometimes tweaking php.ini helps by imposing limits and restrictions
- If you have used non-custom software, you can download newer, patched version and try to merge with what you've got, so it is patched
- Sometimes, e.g. in Wordpress you can enable autoupdate

Also, your server might be compromised to, so you can try rebuilding it. E.g. reprovision the virtual machine.

You can also try requesting help by uploading the website to GitHub, which later can be removed, and then it can be peer-reviewed. The database would not be necessary, it's contest for sure. It would be good to read the logs and see how it was exploited.

The breach of the website is not always also breach of the server. If there was silly mistake in PHP code it doesn't mean there was kernel vulnerability which was exploited.

In summary, you should edit it in editor and review it properly and then it will be sorted, and eventually it can be patched as well, and then keep the backup every time you change something. There's no way it can be sorted with a command, plus it needs to be patched as well. This involves working with the source code as usual, and not with grep.